# Program crashed during PCL visualization Error

Tags: c++

I am new to PCL(Point Cloud Library).I used the default All-in-one-installer to install the PCL .The visual studio version is 2019.
Now, I want to run the simple PCD visualization code like this:
'''

```
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>

int user_data;

void
viewerOneOff(pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer& viewer)
{
    viewer.setBackgroundColor(1.0, 0.5, 1.0);
    pcl::PointXYZ o;
    o.x = 1.0;
    o.y = 0;
    o.z = 0;
    viewer.addSphere(o, 0.25, "sphere", 0);
    std::cout << "i only run once" << std::endl;

}

void
viewerPsycho(pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer& viewer)
{
    static unsigned count = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Once per viewer loop: " << count++;
    viewer.removeShape("text", 0);
    viewer.addText(ss.str(), 200, 300, "text", 0);

    //FIXME: possible race condition here:
    user_data++;
}

int
main()
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile("C:/Users/Shinelon/Desktop/test_pcd.pcd", *cloud);

    pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

    //blocks until the cloud is actually rendered
    viewer.showCloud(cloud);

    //use the following functions to get access to the underlying more advanced/powerful
    //PCLVisualizer

    //This will only get called once
    viewer.runOnVisualizationThreadOnce(viewerOneOff);

    ////This will get called once per visualization iteration
    viewer.runOnVisualizationThread(viewerPsycho);
    while (!viewer.wasStopped())
    {
        //you can also do cool processing here
        //FIXME: Note that this is running in a separate thread from viewerPsycho
        //and you should guard against race conditions yourself...
        user_data++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

'''

The Result is:

I don't get any error, the compilation was successful. When I run, it will display a window,  and then the program  crashes.

I can not find the cause.Could someone help me?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Run it under a debugger to see where it crashes and check variables that are causing that?

Comment: I tried this approach.When the program runs on this line(pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");), The compiler tells me to look for a file which is called cloud_viewer.cpp. But I didn't write it, and then I found it in ‪F:\PCL\PCL 1.11.0\share\doc\pcl-1.11\tutorials\sources\cloud_viewer\ .  However, it's just a sample program. I am so confused.

Comment: I found a solution which was to reinstall the graphics driver. It works fine.

Comment: Well done! If you write an answer which explains what graphics hardware and OS you have, and which version(s) of the driver you un/reinstalled, that could be useful to future readers or people searching.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know the version number of the previous NVIDIA driver on my laptop.
Coincidentally, a game running on my computer crashed yesterday because of "nvwgf2umx.DLL".The official solution is to reinstall the latest version of the NVIDIA driver which I did later.
As a result, the game worked, and the bugs in the post disappeared.
I hope that this answer will be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

OP seems to be using Windows. However, this bug can also happen in Ubuntu 22.04 with PCL 1.12.1 and has to do with VTK 9.x. The issue has already been fixed in the master branch, though it is not available yet on the package manager. Building PCL from source since the fix should work.